# the odds of winning a modified "6 from 49" lottery?

Tags: probability-distributions, lotteries

I've been staring at this one for a few hours and not sure where to start (caveat: my statistics is EXTREMELY rusty), but Google didn't offer up much to help.

The scenario is an age-old lottery of 49 choose 6, except for the fact your ticket has a variable number of balls. If you choose 6 balls on your ticket, then the answer is covered ad nauseam (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_mathematics#Information_theoretic_results). However, the catch is members may opt, for a lower fee, to enter only 5 numbers on the ticket. They are excluded from the possibility of matching 6 balls, obviously, however they can still make all sub-prizes of matching 1 through 5 balls, albeit the odds are worse.

How would one go about calculating the odds for the secondary prizes when members play 5, 4, 3 etc balls on a draw that is always 6. Conversely, how could the odds be calculated when the allowed number of picks on a ticket are MORE than the number of draws (6). Obviously in this case, there is not a single "jackpot" and odds overall improve.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I am just guessing quickly: the number of possibilities to draw $5$ numbers out of $49$ is -as we know- $49\choose 5$. Since you have chosen $6$ you have ${49\choose 5} {6\choose 5}$ possibilities to match $5$ or $6$ numbers. From this you should subtract $49\choose 6$. I believe that your statistics isn't that rusty. Can you think about this ? By looking at a simpler example with much smaller numbers it should be possible to enumerate all the possibilities.

Comment: Thank you very much @KurtG. Unfortunately, the proposed solution ends up being a negative number (6 from 49 are more possibilities than 5 from 49 cross 5 from 6). In looking at it for a simple case, I get very confused at the last part. Take a very small lottery of 4 balls, where 2 are chosen as the "winning numbers" Total possibilities are 6. Now take someone on a "downgraded" ticket who only chose 1 ball. Total possibilities are 4. I have no idea how to treat the 6 possibilities of the winning combo vs the 4 possibilities of the member's single ball choice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to solve this, using a modification of the hypergeometric distro. Feel free to check work, but this seems to pass a sanity check:

N = ball pool depth

H = house ticket size

Y = your ticket size (less, equal, or greater than H)

C = correct hits

$\binom{H}{C} {N - H \choose Y - C}$

Where the denominator is the part I'm slightly fuzzy on, thinking whereby the maximum possibilities is based on the house's draw, which would be ${N \choose H}$.

Comment: In your 4-ball lottery above, labeling balls W, X, Y, Z, the possible winning pairs are WX, WY, WZ, XY, XZ, YZ. If you choose 1 ball, (A, B, C, D) you have a 50/50 chance of matching. Not sure if this matches your formula. This would be N = 4, H=2, Y=1, C=1.

Comment: @housed_off_space thanks for that. It actually matches a denominator where the maximum possibilities are calc'd off YOUR ticket and not the house's., so looks like I figured poorly on the denom. Resultant: $${N \choose Y}$$

Comment: For any future readers, I meant (W, X, Y, Z) in place of (A, B, C, D).